# Qt + Phonon: doesn't play on some computers

Tags: windows, qt, media-player, phonon

I have a problem with my application after deploying to a clean machine. These are the results of running the application:

1. **Win7 Home**: After installing ffdshow the program plays wmv, mp3.
2. **Vista Home**:  With ffdshow installed, it plays mp3, but not wmv
3. **WinXP** (without service packs): Doesn't play wmv, mp3, even with ffdshow installed. The program can find 38 backends, mp3 and wmv are among them. It does play wav files.
4. Everything plays just fine on the computer where the project is built, even if many formats are disabled in ffdshow.

The plugins folder is put besides the exe file and contains a phonon_backends folder with phonon_ds94.dll.

Can someone explain me how to make the program play files on computers where Qt is not installed?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the mp3 files not playing, but did you remember to deploy QtOpenGL4.dll as well on the machines that won't play video? On Windows, [the Phonon backend relies on this DLL](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/what_is_needed_for_deploying_a_phonon_based_application) and will just silently sit there and do nothing when it's not present.

Sjwarner's suggestion to try Dependency Walker is a good one, especially in cases like this where plugin DLLs are dynamically loaded.

Comment: Oh, I really forgot about OpenGL... yeah, probably it would solve the problem... I will able to check this solution at the evening, I will update. Thanks!

Comment: Just adding of this file didn't help. Other files are present. I will work with dependency walker to find what is not presented.

Comment: Just to be sure...is the folder called "phonon_backend" or "phonon_backends"? (See your question) There should be no 's' at the end. I'm sure it's a typo, but I have to ask.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the comment... I don't have the program before my eyes but I thing it's right because it cannot find backends. And I experimented with folder name - as soon as I renamed it the program could not find any backends. But anyway I will check it twice.

Comment: See the comment to the @sjwarner. Thanks

Comment: Do I need to add something to the pro file?

Comment: +1 I had a similar problem where the qmediaplayer example app worked on a development machine but not on others.  Audio clips wouldn't load and the no audio outputs were listed. It turned out to be caused by the missing `phonon_backend` directory

Answer (score 1):

This first thing I'd do is to give [**Dependency Walker**](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) a go. I'd run it with all of the deployed states you've detailed above and see if there are any differences between the dlls used by the app in each case.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot about this tool too. Good idea! Thanks, I will post update this evening.

Comment: Okay, I've run the DW on the exe file. Everything looks fine but several strange things:
1) It doesn't show qtopengl4.dll in the tree.
2) It shows IESHIM.dll is requires. 
What doesn't it mean and what to do now? Maybe I've run something wrong? I'm not sure that I understood your idea about different states properly. I've just run on the dll and looked on the tree of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact issue, and I fixed it by installing a codec pack. This is the one I used: [K-Lite Mega Codec pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm) (be sure NOT to install the two browser add-ons at the end)